# Tab Teams app won't display in meeting stage or side chat

Tags: teams-toolkit, microsoft-teams-js

All,

I created a default Tab app from the sample in VS Code and the app is able to load by itself just fine. However, I added capability to be loaded as part of a group meeting and when I try to load the app, I get the message below:
**Refused to display 'https://www.microsoft.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.**

Loading the app by itself continues to work.

I've tried changing the content to the bare minimum but still won't load.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reaching out to us, you can follow this sample https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx-Samples/tree/dev/hello-world-in-meeting to add a Tab in the side panel of a meeting.

Comment: Thanks for the example and reply. This sample shows up on the side chat but still the URL is blocked when clicked. This could be because I haven't deployed the app to Azure?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this related question:
[How to fix Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56391081/how-to-fix-refused-to-display-in-a-frame-because-it-set-x-frame-options-to-sa)
I guess the reason is the page cannot be embedded.
Azure is not necessary, you can try using some tool like ngrok to redirect the url.